# Code refactor for "this." in function

Tags: typescript

I have so many "this." in code:

```
calculate(){
  this.value1 = this.fabrika.calc(this.value2);
  this.value4 = this.other.other_calc(this.value10);
  // etc
}
```

how i can do something like:

```
calculate(){
  with this{  // error 
     value1 = fabrika.calc(value2);
     value4 = other.other_calc(value10);
  }
}
```

it is more pretty code

Comment: No way to do this AFAIK, though you could alias `this` to `t` to reduce the length. (Alternatively, use closures instead of classes)

Comment: you can use the destructuring syntax `let { value2, value10 } = this;` to pull multiple values into scope in one line. though, any assignments will not affect `this` of course.

Comment: Well, there is a real [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) keyword, but there some [strong arguments against using it](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this example helps, but just declare a local variable to something more legiable like i did in this example for const foods = this.foods; lol not much better but better than this.foods in the params.

```
const foodMenu = {
    foods: ['rice', 'beans', 'beef'],
    getRandomFood: function () {
        return () => {
            const foods = this.foods;
            const food_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * foods.length);
            return foods[food_index];
        }
    }
}

const getFood = foodMenu.getRandomFood();
console.log(getFood());
```

All in all I recommend new declaration for variables and place it in your code where necessary and leaving comments :D